# How to set size of JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

Hello I was just wondering is it possible to set the size of a JFormattedTextField like it is with a regular JTextField for example.

Below I have a normal JTextField and am just setting it to a decent size.

```
 textField = new JTextField(20);//Setting the JTextFields size to 20
```

But say I was to have  a JFormattedTextField as below how would I set the size of it I cant seem to find anything relating to it online any suggestions or help greatly appreciated.

```
 textField =new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("###,###"));//This JFormattedTextField is being set so only decimals may be entered into it
```

Comment: to solve problems like this, it helps to read the api doc - of the class you are working on __and__ its ancestors ;) The default javadoc has a block titled "Methods declared from XX" for each of the ancestors ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `JFormattedTextField` extends from `JTextField`, you can use all of the methods available to the parent with the child, here the `setColumns(...)` method which will set the value for the displayed column width of the component. This is all as per the [JFormattedTextField API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

For example:

```
// in the field declaration section
private JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("###,###"));

// .....

// in the constructor
textField.setColumns(20);
```